# What happens to a qubit in superposition that goes through a Pauli-X gate?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

Suppose, you have the following quantum circuit:

[image: Quantum Circuit]
We start with a qubit and put it through a Hadamard gate which will put the qubit into superposition.

Now, we apply the Pauli-X gate to the qubit in superposition (which flips the bit) and then we measure the result.

Regardless of whether the circuit makes sense or not, my question is: To flip a bit, the bit must be known. Does this mean, applying the Pauli-X gate automatically leads to a collapse of the superposition?

Comment: I'd have a look at the concept of unitary time evolution, which such operations fall under'

Comment: No. That is how a classical X gate would work. The challenge in building quantum gates is that they work on superpositions of 0 and 1 as well. If you put in a superposition of 0 and 1, you get out the same superposition of 1 and 0.

Answer (score 4):

This

> to flip a bit, the bit must be known

is completely incorrect. The Pauli X gate, like *all* unitary evolution, applies linearly: if
$$
X|0⟩ = |1⟩
\quad \text{and} \quad
X|1⟩ = |0⟩,
$$
then $X$ acting on a superposition $\alpha |0⟩+ \beta |1⟩$ will produce a superposition of the outcomes, i.e.
\begin{align}
X \left( \alpha |0⟩+ \beta |1⟩ \right)
& = 
\alpha X|0⟩+ \beta X|1⟩
\\ & =
\alpha |1⟩+ \beta |0⟩,
\end{align}
or in matrix form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\ \beta\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}\beta \\ \alpha\end{pmatrix}.
$$
There's no collapse of the wavefunction until (and unless) you explicitly perform a projective measurement.

Answer (score 1):

Three videos by Micheal Nielsen explain this at length, quite simply:

- [Our first quantum gate: the quantum NOT gate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDDSjsQLv80)
- [The Hadamard Gate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6gOp_o7Bi8)
- [Measuring a Qubit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMbh0GgCN7I)

Rather than thinking of it as a "flip" think of it as a rotation. The [Pauli-X gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Pauli-X_gate_(=_NOT_gate)) rotates the Bloch sphere around the X-axis by $\pi$ radians. It maps $\vert0\rangle$ to $\vert1\rangle$, $\vert1\rangle$ to $\vert0\rangle$ and ([the superposition](https://youtu.be/JDDSjsQLv80?t=1m31s)) $\alpha\vert0\rangle+\beta\vert1\rangle$ to $\alpha\vert1\rangle+\beta\vert0\rangle$. Two Hadamard or Pauli gates in a row are equivalent to having none, they undo themselves.

Comment: On the advice of Kyle Kanos and Stéphane Rollandin rather than editing the other answer, which resulted in my first rejection, I have posted this information separately as an additional (similar?) answer. It was rejected for deviating from the intent of the original post and for not making it easier to understand.